# Arranging fields side by side in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to create a page structure like below -

Below is the code which i am trying to do -

```
   <apex:pageBlockSection >

    <apex:panelGrid columns="1">
    <apex:outputText value="{!test}" label="Name" title="Name"/>


        <apex:outputField value="{!test.Status__c}"/><br/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!test.Cost__c}" label="Cost" rendered="{!!isNew}"/>
                    <apex:outputText value="" label="" rendered="" id=""/>

                    </apex:panelGrid>
    <apex:panelGrid columns="4" style="position:relative;right: 35%;">


        <apex:outputlabel value="Address" style="font-weight: bold;">
        <br/>

             <apex:outputPanel >
                <apex:outputField value="{!test.Street}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!test.PostalCode}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Country}"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:outputlabel>       
            <apex:map width="450px" height="200px" mapType="roadmap" zoomLevel="15"
                      center="">
            </apex:map>
         </apex:panelGrid>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

The above code is creating the below structure -

Please help to create a sturucture like the 1st pic.I cant use any html code. All native salesforce tags need to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code would look more like this:

```
<apex:panelGrid columns="3" style="table-layout: fixed" width="100%">
    <!-- column 1 -->
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
      <apex:outputField value="{!test.Name}" />
      <apex:outputField value="{!test.Cost__c}" />
      <apex:outputField value="{!test.Amount}" />
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <!-- column 2 -->
    <apex:panelGrid columns="1">
      <apex:outputLabel value="Address" />
      <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.MailingStreet}" />
      <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.MailingCity}" />
      <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.MailingState}" />
      <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.MailingPostalCode}" />
      <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.MailingCountry}" />
    </apex:panelGrid>
    <!-- column 3 -->
    <apex:map width="450px" height="200px" mapType="roadmap" zoomLevel="15"
                  center="{!Contact.MailingStreet},{!Contact.MailingCity},{!Contact.MailingState},{!Contact.MailingPostalCode},{!Contact.MailingCountry}">
    </apex:map>
</apex:panelGrid>
```